# Any good reason not to withdraw vote account rewards?

Tags: staking, rewards, vote-account

Running a validator and getting rewards to the vote account balance, is there any reason not to withdraw them?
Any benefit or profit, ranking or something else that worth to save the incoming reward SOLS in the vote account?  (not the stakes, only the rewards)

- worth mentioning that in our case its a self validator with 100% commission

Thanks

Comment: I think there is no reason not to withdraw from vote account. Did you find any reference about this?